# Setting up UDP client (python)

Tags: python, sockets

I tried to set up a UDP client and see if I can print the data like below:

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 80

# create a socket object 
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

#send some data
client.sendto("AAABBBCCC", (target_host, target_port))

#receive some data
data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

print data
```

So I execute it with
$python udp_client.py

But then the shell just stuck at this line in the code
data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `recvfrom` is a blocking call, it will block until there is data to read. https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Comment: you might want to reduce 4096...